# Why can't we use the residue theorem to evaluate indefinite integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis

Integrals evaluated with complex analysis have to be in the form:
$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x) \, dx \,, \, \int_{-\infty}^0f(x) \, dx\,, \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx\,, \, \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x) \, dx$$
But why can't we evaluate it using this form:
$$\int_{A}^{x}f(t) \, dt + C$$
Where $~A~$ can be included in the constant term.

It can calculate all possible definite integrals across $x$ and $f(x)$. But why cant we use it.

So instead of $$\oint_{\Gamma}^{}f(z)\ dz = \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-R}^{R}f(z)\ dz \ + \oint_{complex\ terms}^{}f(z) \ dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^n Res(f(z),C_k)$$

Why cant we have:
$$\oint_{\Gamma}^{}f(z)\ dz = \lim_{R\rightarrow x} \int_{0}^{R}f(z)\ dz \ + \oint_{complex\ terms}^{}f(z) \ dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^n Res(f(z),C_k)$$

So we can evaluate the integral  of this function for more than one type of reigon. So we can evaluate the integral inbetween any $x \  \epsilon \ [a, b]$

Comment: Indeed, we can. I submitted a paper about this in a high school math competition and won a small prize. :)

Comment: There is not requirement in complex analysis that integrals have those forms. It is just that when you use the *Residue Theorem* to evaluate an integral, it has to have a closed path. So you either have to go around a full circle ($0$ to $2\pi$), or you have make the part of the path you don't want to be zero, which is most easily accomplished by taking a limit with that part going to $\infty$. So the method lends itself to evaluating integrals of the sort you've listed. But that doesn't mean that even the Residue method, much less Complex Analysis as a whole, is strictly limited to them.

Comment: @Szeto can you post an answer with it maybe?

Comment: @Szeto Please can you leave a link.